# InDesign: change dimensions of mulitple objects

Tags: adobe-indesign, transform, dimensions

Is there a way to alter the size of multiple objects at once?

For example those rounded rectangles in the screenshot have a height of 10 mm, but I want to reduce all of them to 8 mm. From what I know I would have to select every single one of them and then adjust their size.

[image]

In applications like Sketch for example, you can select them all and change the height parameter to your desired value to change them all at once. Is this also somehow possible in InDesign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is an option... Choose one of the rectangles and set the width and height on the Control palette. Then, select other rectangles and choose Object => Transform Again => Transform Sequence Again Individually.

Comment: Hi! What I wanted to change was the height. The problem ist that when I select all of them it only shows me the combined height of all of them, not the individual height of each object. The same would apply for the width if I had stacked them horizontally.

Comment: awesome. That worked. Could you edit your original post so I can mark it as answer ? :)

Comment: Done:) Glad I could help:)